# Mysql/PHP: Substract 1 day from chosen input date field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have one input field, if user choose a date (format YYYY-MM-DD) then the page reloads (already using jquery/ajax for this), and then it should be getting the results from the day before the date user has inserted into the field.

I want to get a value from db, the day before the selected date user inputs.

Using DATE in mysql db, maybe it`s better to use timestamp ? Easier to modify and play with ?

Comment: That is barebones basic PHP: presenting a form to a user, getting data submitted from the form, and using that data to fetch/display other data. We are not here to teach you the basics.

Comment: You can do this in your query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: MySQL date arithmetic is easy. `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` yields yesterday, for example. All that works equally well with `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, and `DATETIME` data types. PHP has similar capabilities. But please clarify what you are trying to do with page refreshes.

Comment: You're using AJAX... to reload a page?? what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have `YYYY-MM-DD` values, then using a `DATE` (SQL datatype) column is fine. For storing values that have both date and time components, (i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS`) we'd use `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` datatype for the column.

Working with those SQL datatypes is essentially the same. The choice of which of those datatypes to use is really a matter of selecting the most appropriate type for the actual data we need to represent.

For `DATE`, `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` datatype columns, to pull rows with values that are a day *before* the specified value, we can use a predicate like this:

```
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.mydatecol >= '2014-08-27' + INTERVAL -1 DAY
   AND t.mydatecol <  '2014-08-27'
```

(This same pattern can extend to any range around a specified value, before and/or after a specified value, and any number of months, days, minutes, etc.)

For a `DATE` column, to return rows for just one previous day, where we are looking to match a *single* value in the column, we can just use equality comparison (instead of a range comparison), e.g.

```
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.mydatecol = '2014-08-27' + INTERVAL -1 DAY
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explaination. That`s the best answer i`ve seen for what i`m been looking for! Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
DATE(DATE_ADD('2014-08-29', INTERVAL -1 DAY))
```